# Scrapy css selector re gives broken json string

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, python-3.6

Hey I am newbie to Python and especially scrappy I am trying to scrap [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/)  . But i am stuck with one problem. I am this regular expression to get json string from response

`__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__ =*(.*\});\};` 
But it gives broken json string some times e.g fr this  [walmart product](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Riders-by-Lee-Women-s-On-the-Go-Performance-Capri/145227527)  Due to which json.loads fails . Is this issue with regx or scrapy .I am not getting why this is happening

Comment: Please give a sample JASON, show what is the desired output and what is the actual output.

Comment: here is smaple json [json file](https://gist.github.com/afrazahmad21/3f76f9010cc847319dcfd8ef4396151a)

Comment: desired output is valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy/Parsel's `Selector` `.re()` and `.re_first()` have the (unfortunately) default behavior of replacing HTML character entities references.
And this can cause JSON decoding to fail.

Illustration with your sample URL in scrapy shell. Your regular expression does work, it selects the data you want:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.walmart.com/ip/Riders-by-Lee-Women-s-On-the-Go-Performance-Capri/145227527 -s USER_AGENT='mozilla'
2017-07-13 15:24:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(..)
2017-07-13 15:24:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.walmart.com/ip/Riders-by-Lee-Women-s-On-the-Go-Performance-Capri/145227527> (referer: None)
>>> data = response.xpath('//script/text()').re_first('__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__ =*(.*\});\};')
>>> data[:25], data[-25:]
(' {"uuid":null,"isMobile":', 'nabled":true,"seller":{}}')
```

But decoding this string as JSON fails:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 40598 (char 40597)
>>> data[40500:40650]
'{"values":["<br /> <b>Riders by Lee Women\'s On the Go Performance Capri</b> <br /> <ul>  <li>21" Inseam</li>  <li>Rib knit waist with button and zippe'
```

A double-quote character is causing trouble.

You can use the `replace_entities=False` argument to not replace entities:

```
>>> dataraw = response.xpath('//script/text()').re_first('__WML_REDUX_INITIAL_STATE__ =*(.*\});\};', replace_entities=False)
>>> dataraw[40500:40650]
'{"values":["<br /> <b>Riders by Lee Women\'s On the Go Performance Capri</b> <br /> <ul>  <li>21&quot; Inseam</li>  <li>Rib knit waist with button and '
```

See how `&quot;` is left as-is.

And now you can decode the string a JSON:

```
>>> d = json.loads(dataraw)
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['uuid', 'isMobile', 'isBot', 'isAdsEnabled', 'isEsiEnabled', 'isInitialStateDeferred', 'isServiceWorkerEnabled', 'isShellRequest', 'productId', 'product', 'showTrustModal', 'productBasicInfo', 'fulfillmentOptions', 'feedback', 'backLink', 'offersOrder', 'sellersHeading', 'fdaCompliance', 'recommendationMap', 'header', 'footer', 'addToRegistry', 'addToList', 'ads', 'btvMap', 'postQuestion', 'autoPartFinder', 'getPromoStatus', 'discoveryModule', 'lastAction', 'isAjaxCall', 'accessModeEnabled', 'seller'])
>>>
```

`replace_entities` was introduced in parsel v1.2.0. (see https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/pull/88)

Comment: which scrapy version you are using @paul because i am getiing TypeError: re_first() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_entities'

Comment: `TypeError: re_first() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_entities'`

Comment: Please upgrade parsel to 1.2 (`pip install --upgrade parsel`). parsel is a dependency of Scrapy